# How to block push notification removal

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, toast

My problem is that I send a push notification to the notification bar but when I start this application from program list then the notification is removed from the notification bar.

Is it possible to block this behavior? I want to remove this notification when the user selects this possibility on the app or swipe out from notification bar.
Thanks for your help in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You send notification not to the notification bar but to Action Center in WP 8.1?
You send push notification to you app through WNS?
In the event handler for OnLaunched in your application is not called Remove notification list for cleaning?

Comment: I use WNS and I get notification to Action Center in WP 8.1, but I didn't use nothing which remove these notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I'm sorry.

If you are asking about this scenario:

1. your application is not running
2. push notification comes to the device through the WNS. Alert
3. appear in the list in the Action Center (BindToShellToast)
4. you you launch the application from the application list or by clicking on an alert in Action Center in WP 8.1

After this Action Center deletes all alerts that were taken when the application has failed to start.

As I know, in this scenario, the notification  are always removed from the Action Center after activation you app.

The Action Center is designed to hold and display the notification that are get when the application does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in the ability to delete notifications from the Action Centre when you start application ...

I was able to avoid removing alerts from the Action Centre but only when you run the application from the list of programs.

When you run the application via clicking on an alert in Action Centre that alerts are removed.
Im use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.

i'm can send sample test application if you have not yet found a solution.